# Find area under a curve using c++ and a file

Tags: c++, fstream

I have updated the code and now I know how to store the first two number into x1 and z1 but how do I let it into x2 and z2 in order to calculate the area? Thanks.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

double x1=0;
double x2=0;
double z1=0;
double z2=0;
double n;
double sum;
double area;

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("xydata.dat");
    infile.ignore(1000, '\n') ;
    while(!infile.eof())
    {
            infile>>n;
            if(n>=20.00&&n<=20.50)
            {
                    x1=n
            }
            else
            {
                    z1=n
             }

area = (x1+x2)*(z2-z1)/2;

}

    cout<<"The sum of all are under the curve is "<<sum<<"."<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and the file is here:
xydata.dat

x values    y values
20.00       0
20.02       15
20.04       27
20.06       39
20.08       54
20.10       65
20.12       75
20.14       84
20.16       93
20.18       101
20.20       108
20.22       113
20.24       116
20.26       115
20.28       112
20.30       107
20.32       100
20.34       92
20.36       83
20.38       74
20.40       64
20.42       53
20.44       39
20.46       27
20.48       15
20.50       0

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: I just don't know how to continue this

Comment: Why not go back to basics and read in the file and write it out. Ie. Tow numbers per line.

Comment: And I think what I did is wrong

Comment: It's generally helpful if you keep your questions specific.  Such as: How do I implement X formula into C++ code and have it return an area?

Comment: Sorry it's my first time here. My question is" how do I store the data points using c++ so that I can sum all the areas using the formula A=(x1+x2)*(y2-y1)/2"

Answer (score 1):

Is this a homework? (Not posting any code due to the previous question)

I am assuming you want the area between the x axis and the curve. Here is a shortcut:

Consider every pair of consecutive coordinates specifying a rectangle, with a triangle sitting on top of it. You get the rectangle's area by multiplying the (differences in x) with (the smaller y). and then get the triangle's area by the (difference in x), multiplied by (the difference in y), and having the half of it. Add these two areas and it will give you an approximate area under the curve for the pair of coordinates. Repeat this procedure for all consecutive pairs of coordinates and add them up.

Comment: I'm mainly trying to figure out how to store 4 numbers in different points from a file

Comment: In that case please update your question to actually ask THAT.

Comment: Ohh, I am sorry I misinterpreted the question then.

You already have four variables for four numbers. You do not need to store all coordinates. First read just the first pair. Then read in one pair at a time and calculate with those. and once you calculate area, just assign the values of the new coordinates to the old ones.

And for reading I would recommend simply 

infile >> x >> y;

instead of your implemented approach. In your approach it may be a problem if the y values fall within the 20.0-20.5 range.

Comment: That's okay. I think I will try to do that and come back if I fail to have the result. Thanks.

Comment: I am getting 0's for all of the sums